# Transforming native-query to named-query in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a simple native-query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    permission p
WHERE
    p.USER_ID = ?
        OR p.ROLE_ID IN (SELECT
            r.id
        FROM
            user u
                JOIN
            role r ON u.ID = r.USER_ID
        WHERE
            r.ROLE_TYPE_ID = ?)
```

and I want to transform this query into a named-query (JPQL) like this:

```
SELECT p
FROM Permission p
WHERE p.user =:user OR p.role IN p.user.roles
```

But the problem is that this is not working: I can't user `IN` like this. Any sugestions or ideas how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Best regards,

JB

Comment: I see no issue in which you should not putting it as a native query.

Comment: use `MEMBER OF` instead of `IN`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to translate your native query as it is in JPA First. See below sample.

```
SELECT p FROM Permission p

    WHERE 
         p.user =:user 
    OR 
         p.role IN (
                     SELECT r from User as u JOIN u.roles as r where r.roleTypeId = :roleTypeId
                   )
```

Now Add/Modify conditions as per your requirements.

**Note :** Kindly Accept The Answer if it helped you